# Write a program using 1-D arrays with values from a random generator to print out how many times each combination was rolled by a pair of dice

Tags: java, arrays, dice

The goal of the assignment is to use parallel 1-D arrays, but 2-D arrays are also allowed.

I can print out the different combinations such as 1,1 (otherwise known as snake eyes) rolled by the pair of dice.

Trying to print out the number of times each combination was rolled without printing the combination the same number of times it was rolled is difficult.

Ex:

Enter the number of times you want to roll a pair of dice: 
5

You rolled: 1 and 5 a total of 1 times *- What I don't want*

You rolled: 4 and 3 a total of 1 times

**You rolled: 1 and 5 a total of 2 times** *- For duplicates this is all I want to print*

You rolled: 3 and 3 a total of 1 times

You rolled: 2 and 2 a total of 1 times

I know the loop for printing it out right after it increments the combo array (which holds the number of times each combination was rolled) is not correct, but I am stuck on how to modify it.

I consider combo[0][0] to be the number of times 1,1 is rolled, combo[0][1] to be the number of times 1,2 is rolled, and so on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice {

Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random diceRoll = new Random();
    int numRolls;
    int[] dice1 = new int [1000];
    int[] dice2 = new int [1000];
    int[][] combo = new int[6][6];


public void getRolls() 
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to roll a pair of dice: ");
    numRolls = read.nextInt();

    dice1 = new int[numRolls];
    dice2 = new int[numRolls];

    for (int i = 0; i < dice1.length; i++)
    {
        dice1[i] = diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice2[i] = diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("\n");



    for (int j = 0; j < combo.length; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < combo[0].length; k++)
        {
            combo[j][k] = 0;
        }
    }

   for (int m = 0; m < numRolls; m++)
    {
        combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1]++;

        System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice1[m] + " and " + 
        dice2[m] + " a total of " + combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1] + 
        " times");
    }
```

Comment: What is the wrong output of your code? Can you detail a bit more please?

Comment: I think what you're saying is that everything calculates correctly, but you're getting duplicate lines written out? Such as seeing `You rolled: 3 and 2 a total of 4 times` more than once in the output?

Comment: @Ickster Yes that is what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Tomaz Fernandes If I roll 1,1 on a pair of dice two times when I rolled 5 times, I only want to print out once that I got it twice.

Comment: You should then separate the combo calculation loop from the printing loop. Is the order it’s printed relevant to you?

Comment: @TomazFernandes is right; because the printing is in the calculation loop, you'll always print `numRolls` statements.

Comment: @Tomaz Fernandes No the order of printing is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer:

I made the printing loop separate from the combo calculation loop. 
If the combo value for the combination is 1, then I simply print it out stating it was rolled 1 time.
If the combo value for the combination was greater than 1, I print it out at the first occurrence stating it was rolled that many times, then set the combo value for that combination equal to 0. Only combos with at least a combo value of 1 are printed, so duplicate lines cannot be printed (i.e. 1,1 rolled 4 times only prints on one line now instead of 4 separate lines).

```
    for (int m = 0; m < numRolls; m++)
    {
        combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1]++;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < numRolls; m++)
    {
        if (combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1] > 1)
        {
            System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice1[m] + " and " + dice2[m] + " a total of " + combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1]   + " time(s)");
            combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1] = 0;
        }

        if (combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1] == 1)
        {
        System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice1[m] + " and " + dice2[m] + " a total of " + combo[dice1[m] - 1][dice2[m] - 1] + " time(s)");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the combo calculation loop from the printing loop. If the order is not relevant as you stated, that should give you the correct output you’re looking for. Happy coding!